# The hierarchy of the type activity is inconsistent when extending ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

Hi I've got new v7 support library with appcompat actionbar and when I want to extend from ActionBarActivity as documented [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), eclipse show me this error

```
The hierarchy of the type testActivity is inconsistent
```

and when I move my courser on ActionBarActivity class it says

```
The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

now how can I Solve this issue?

Comment: `Clean` on both libraries didn't help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you should use new support v4 library that just has been released in sdk v18

Comment: problems solved thank you. I should have imported it as a Eclipse library

Comment: actually v4 should not be a part of the main project, but a part of the v7 user library

Comment: I was working on Unity development and had the same error. The problem for me was due to min SDK version. Unity requires minimum 2.3.1 and I set up the whole thing for 1.6!

Answer (score 4):

I run in exactly the same issue and find thanks to tyczj a better solution, I think. If you have correctly setup the v7 library: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library You should NOT need to add again the v4 since it is included in v7 folder.

(Since you add the new v4 to solve your problem, I suppose you did not really use the one from v7 because in the v7 it IS the new one)

My post: [If I use new " V7 Appcompat library ", do I still need " V4 Support Library " for a minimum SDK = 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084808/if-i-use-new-v7-appcompat-library-do-i-still-need-v4-support-library-fo)