# Android get Error inflating class in XML file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

i'm define this below layout XML for activity. in this layout i'm define slide menu and i'm using `Fragment` and `FrameLayout` with supported in older of android sdk. but i get error in Android 2.2 this error is not API Level > 8, how to resolve this layout problem and fix that for Android 2.2?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                        tools:context="com.example.slidemenu.MainActivity"
                                        android:background="#ffffff">
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="0dip"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true">
</ListView>
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:name="ir.tsms.Fragments.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in Activity my class extends from ActionBarActivity, i'm say again i dont have any problem in android 4, thanks.

```
public class ActivityMain extends ActionBarActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener, NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
```

Error:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class

Comment: Post the full stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `v7` instead of `v4`. because you use `ActionBarActivity` class  :

[Difference between android-support-v7-appcompat and android-support-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4)

Answer (score 0):

public class ActivityMain extends ActionBarActivity

To

public class ActivityMain extends FragmentActivity

Answer (score 0):

maybe print for us this error...

also

> android:layout_gravity="start"

should be set for FrameLayout (parent), not fragment (child). Drawer check its childs not, child's childs. v4 is enough