# Android: What is the difference between "support" and "appcompat"

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat

I have come upon these lines in the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13...'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7...'
```

Until now I thought that for supporting older versions of android you use the AppCompat libs.

So what exactly is the difference between "support" and "appcompat"?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4

Answer (score 2):

**v4 Support Library**

This library is designed to be used with Android 1.6 (API level 4) and higher. It includes the largest set of APIs compared to the other libraries, including support for application components, user interface features, accessibility, data handling, network connectivity, and programming utilities.

**v7 Libraries**

There are several libraries designed to be used with Android 2.1 (API level 7) and higher. These libraries provide specific feature sets and can be included in your application independently from each other.

**v7 appcompat library**

This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design pattern.

Comment: If you're going to copy an answer, at least reference the documentation.