# What is Android MultiDex?

Tags: android, android-multidex

There are many posts about MultiDex. I have experienced, sometimes, errors solved including `multiDexEnabled true` in the `defaultConfig` section of my build.gradle.

But, what exactly is this feature? What are the scenarios for using it?

Answer (score 204, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html):

> Android application (APK) files contain executable bytecode files in the form of Dalvik Executable (DEX) files, which contain the compiled code used to run your app. The Dalvik Executable specification limits the total number of methods that can be referenced within a single DEX file to 65,536, including Android framework methods, library methods, and methods in your own code. Getting past this limit requires that you configure your app build process to generate more than one DEX file, known as a multidex configuration.

So, the feature is: it allows your complex app to compile. The scenarios for using it are when your app fails to compile due to hitting the 64K DEX method reference limit. This appears as a build error, such as:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Comment: Any idea how large a codebase this would be (LOC, or rough # of screens)? Are you gonna hit this limit on a simple 5-6 screens app or is it really much further down the line (i.e.:10-20 screens) that you would likely hit it

Comment: @Marchy: Usually, it comes from adding too many libraries. It is difficult for a library-less project to hit this limit.

Comment: I have a small app that uses about 5 google support libraries as well as Fabric.io and 2 or 3 other third party libraries and I have to use multi-dex.

Comment: are there any disadvantages of enabling multidex? why not let it true as default?

Comment: @RafaelLima: There are security issues with the quasi-backport of multidex for pre-Android 5.0 devices. IIRC, it also can cause some problems with your app, if you are trying to use classes that are in a not-yet-loaded DEX file.

Comment: @Marchy for reference, instagram app is single-dex

Answer (score 68):

## It's as simple as this

A single .dex file can have 65,536 methods(references) so if the number of references exceeds 65,536, you go with multidex.

## More Explanation!

An android application program is compiled into a .dex file which in turn zipped to a single .apk file.
DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine) uses .dex file/files to execute bytecodes.

**What causes the number of references to exceed 65,536 limits?**
Methods written by you + Android Framework methods + Third party library(eg Volley,Retrofit, Facebook SDK etc) methods.
I have read "somewhere"
App Compat 24.2.1 contains 16.5k methods
Google Play Services GCM 9.6.1 contains 16.7k methods
So if you have created a simple Hello world application which has App Compat 24.2.1, you are already **1/4 way** to cross the single dex methods limit

Answer (score 12):

**Accroding Android developer official site.**

```
If your minSdkVersion is set to 21 or higher, multidex is enabled by default and you do not need the multidex support library.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a question from year 2015, so many things changed since.

Comment: it would be better if you could add a link.

Answer (score 1):

*When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods, you encounter a build error that indicates your app has reached the limit of the Android build architecture*

**How to enable MultiDex in your project**

***Bulid.gradle***

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "******"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 8
    versionName "05.15.21.8"
    multiDexEnabled true

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}


    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

*inherit MultiDexApplication*

```
    public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

    private static App instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        MultiDex.install(this);
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static App getInstance ()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        super.onTerminate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

*In your Manifest*

```
 <application
     android:name=".App"
 </application>
```

> Thank You