# Adding external JAR to Android project in ECLIPSE causing "Conversion to Dalvik format failed"

Tags: android, eclipse, email, dalvik

I have problem adding mail.jar and activation.jar to my Android Project.
When I try to launch in emulator I always get this messagge:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Without this two jars everything starts correctly:

```
[2016-01-20 09:49:57 - FT2500-Mobile] Android Launch!
[2016-01-20 09:49:57 - FT2500-Mobile] adb is running normally.
[2016-01-20 09:49:57 - FT2500-Mobile] Performing com.econorma.activities.MainActivity activity launch
[2016-01-20 09:49:58 - FT2500-Mobile] Uploading FT2500-Mobile.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2016-01-20 09:50:01 - FT2500-Mobile] Installing FT2500-Mobile.apk...
[2016-01-20 09:50:27 - FT2500-Mobile] Success!
[2016-01-20 09:50:27 - FT2500-Mobile] Starting activity com.econorma.activities.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2016-01-20 09:50:27 - FT2500-Mobile] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.econorma.ft2500/com.econorma.activities.MainActivity }
```

I tried also to remove Google_play_service.lib and replace with and older one (version 21), but I have a NoClassDefFoundError in javax.activation Mail.

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations! You've exceeded the method id amount. [More info about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588459/what-is-android-multidex).

To use this library, you need to use multidex.
Add this line line into your `dependencies` section inside `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    // Other dependencies
}
```

Also, you need to extend your `Application` class from `MultiDexApplication`

Comment: @AlessandroMattiuzzi Oops. And you're not using gradle?

Comment: Solved installing an older versione of Google Play Service

Comment: @AlessandroMattiuzzi that's good. But i'd consider to switch your build environment to Gradle. It's more flexible and standard for today android development. More community -> less problems :)