# Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list. # methods: 87928 > 65536

Tags: android, gradle

what is main this and how to fix the error

> Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a
>   main-dex list.
>
> ## methods: 87928 > 65536

here is my gradle

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.apoce.app.admin"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.36.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Android MultiDex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588459/what-is-android-multidex)

Comment: how to fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix this error by adding this dependencie to gardle app

```
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
```

and this configuration `multiDexEnabled true` to `defaultConfig`