# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'

Tags: android

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate

> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.

Answer (score 0):

Your application has grown and you need to enable and use MultiDex. Check: [What is Android MultiDex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588459/what-is-android-multidex)

And
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex