# What is the difference between adding dependency with version code and without version code?

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

What is the difference between adding dependency `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'` and `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'`  in **android gradle**.

Because am trying to use quinny898 persistentsearch library which is not supporting in **23.0.0 as ActionBarActivity** is deprecated in new versions.

Comment: I think it will load the newest version of the library.

Comment: @Amy Yes yes . I think so.

Comment: so adding 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7' support all devices. or does it have any problems with latest versions of android?

Comment: @jdoe call `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0` for better approach

Comment: Ya but i was trying to add quinny898 persistentsearch in my app. But adding 23.0.0 causing exception. Have you tried quinny898 persistentsearch?

Comment: @jdoe have a look settings https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch/blob/master/library/build.gradle

Comment: You can share your `Exception`

Comment: adding dependency com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 working fine but when i tried com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0 the following exception occured. 

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.endless.searchbar/com.endless.searchbar.RevealActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features. @IntelliJAmiya (sry for late response)

Comment: @jdoe `ava.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo` That is another case .

Answer (score 1):

**ActionBarActivity** is deprecated. You should use **AppCompatActivity**.

Please read **[v7 Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/support-library/features.html#v7)** .I hope it will helps you .

> Android Support Library package contains several libraries that can
>   be included in your application. Each of these libraries supports a
>   specific range of Android platform versions and set of features.
>
> The important features and version support
>   provided by the Support Libraries to help you decide which of them you
>   should include in your application. In general, we recommend including
>   the v7 support and v7 appcompat libraries, because they support a wide
>   range of Android versions and provide APIs for recommended user
>   interface patterns.

**v7 Libraries**

> There are several libraries designed to be used with Android 2.1 (API
>   level 7) and higher. These libraries provide specific feature sets and
>   can be included in your application independently from each other.

**v7 appcompat library**

> This library adds support for the Action Bar user interface design
>   pattern.

**android:versionCode**

> An integer value that represents the version of the application code,
>   relative to other versions. The value is an integer so that other
>   applications can programmatically evaluate it.

Courtesy goes to **[Difference between android-support-v7-appcompat and android-support-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4)**