# Is v7 appcompat library required for Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm really not experienced with Android.

As mentioned in [Difference between android-support-v7-appcompat and android-support-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4) there are multiple various support libs in the Android. The official Android article http://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html on using Toolbar states that I need to use **v7 appcompat lib**. The problem is... I don't wanna use it, as it makes a mess with everything in the code.

So, is there a way to have a toolbar without using this support lib (v7), since I need only support for Android API level >= 15 (ver. 4.0+), not 2.* or sth? If not, how could I implement it? (This class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html suggests v7 lib is needed).

Further more, is it possible to force Android Studio IDE to generate projects that use no this Compat Support library? (So that I'm not required to change everything related to it - and this includes a lot of work with e.g. theme resource files - so that there's no relations to this support lib)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the Support Library? There's a huge difference between supporting 4.X and 5.X+ devices that AppCompat removes entirely.

Comment: @ianhanniballake what do you mean by difference with 5.x devices when comparing to 4.x devices?

Comment: There's that whole [material design](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) thing that only exists natively on 5.0+ devices.

Comment: Ok. But if I create an app for 4.x, wouldn't it be still able to launch on 5.x devices, but just with different look / ("material") design, and all functionality, like from App Bar, remain the same?

Comment: It'll look totally out of place and antiquated, but it'll run. Not sure why that would be what you'd want to do though?

Comment: Well, so now... it's quite different thing. I probably need to test it on an emulator (and see how it really looks like), because I don't want to upgrade my android phone (4.4 -> 5) due to the fact I want to have a lower ver in the phone in order to test it with it. So maybe you're right. Thanks.