# Android - What does the number 22 in - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

What does the number **22** in the file build.gradle mean - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**22**.2.1?

Part file **build.gradle**

```
dependencies { compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', { exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }) compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1' testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' }
```

Comment: [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4/49167045#49167045), you will get the answer.it is revision number of support library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between android-support-v7-appcompat and android-support-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271429/difference-between-android-support-v7-appcompat-and-android-support-v4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v22 is the api level. 
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1 is the support library for Android Lollipop 5.1