# Having problem with setting app to minSdkVersion 9

Tags: android, api, android-studio

I'm getting an error:

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0]
```

Ok, so what androidx.appcompat:appcompat should I set in order app to support versions from API 9 to 30? I already set the oldest androidx.appcompat:appcompat available in Android Studio. I saw some tuts that tell me to go to Open Module Settings > Flavours but there are no such tab in the current version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)  androidx.appcompat 1.0.0 came at November 2018.
And it doesn't support too old versions. you should use [support libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130004/10908886) for api 9 or higher. For deeper information check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130004/10908886).

Answer (score 0):

androidx is a library that doesn't support to old Android versions. As you can see the mininum sdk that it supports is 14.