# How to configure buildpath after importing appcompact_v7 in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I first imported the `appcompact_v7` project into eclipse by copying that to workspace. Then I added it as a external jar in my original project and referenced the `appcompact_v7` project.

Then I imported :

import `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;` in my original project. But it still says configure build path. And it gives this error:

```
The type android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder$SupportParentable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add appcompat follow these steps:

1. Import appcompat project from **File**>**Import**

   2. Select **Existing Android Code Into Workspace**
   3. Now in your project goto **Properties > Android**
   4. There click **Add** Button and select the appcompat project

This is the valid method of referencing external projects in your project and you should avoid other methods as much as possible.

This would also be helpful to you: [If I use new " V7 Appcompat library ", do I still need " V4 Support Library " for a minimum SDK = 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084808/if-i-use-new-v7-appcompat-library-do-i-still-need-v4-support-library-fo)

Good Luck!

UPDATE: Since you are asking about jar dependencies mismatch, you can see where these jar files are in console. You can copy one jar and replace in each location. However this is not the recommended way. You can follow this link and do as suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18039006/2741586

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did exactly the same thing but as soon as I imported and added it to the original project, it gives an error message in console 
SHA-1: 48c94ae70fa65718b382098237806a5909bb096e
Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: You are using two support-v4.jar different in the lib and in the project.