# i have problems in importing some package

Tags: android

I have problem in import the following package. Please help me to solve this issue..

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

thanks all in advance.

Comment: what is the problem?You don't have add the v4 dependency if you already have v7. Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084808/if-i-use-new-v7-appcompat-library-do-i-still-need-v4-support-library-fo

Comment: actually i have develop project in android eclipse.. so please give solution with respective of android eclipse

Comment: you can refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998368/the-import-android-support-v7-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: ' compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0 '  ' compile com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3 '  add in your depandency of build.gradle file.

Comment: Will you please help me.. I have get error in R file of this. I have develop project in eclipse.. please help me out.